# How do I find all files in subfolders that are missing a specific property?

Tags: windows-10, search, photos, steam, file-attributes

On my main Windows 10 machine, I take a lot of video game screenshots with Steam. Within Steam's screenshot folder (`Steam\userdata\<user_id>\760\remote`), it creates a new folder for every game, which itself contains a `screenshots` folder that then contains the screenshots you've taken.

I've once backed up these screenshots to Google Photos. In order to get the screenshots to upload with the correct date, I used exiftool to set the "Date Taken" property on all the image files that existed at the time.

I did not delete these files after uploading, as I still want Steam to recognise them.

Since then, I've taken more screenshots and want to upload these new ones without re-uploading the ones that have already been uploaded (Google will recognise them as duplicates, but it's still a waste of my bandwidth and time with 165 folders and tens of thousands of images).

The only difference I can think of between the new screenshots and the previously uploaded ones are that the new ones will be lacking the "Date Taken" property. I don't have the date I uploaded the last batch on hand, and while I could maybe get that from Google Photos, I'd rather not.

Is there any way to search a top-level folder recursively for files that are missing a specific property?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to find a similar question that helped me figure out how to do it.

[Get Attributes listed in the “Details” Tab with Powershell](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49214905/get-attributes-listed-in-the-details-tab-with-powershell)

The answer for that question links to a Microsoft Dev Blog in which the author links a script and explains how to use it in order to get properties from a recursive list of files.

[List Music File Metadata in a CSV and Open in Excel with PowerShell](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/scripting/list-music-file-metadata-in-a-csv-and-open-in-excel-with-powershell/)

The exact steps I took were as follows:

1. Downloaded the *Get-FileMetaDataReturnObject.ps1* script [from the TechNet Gallery](https://gallery.technet.microsoft.com/scriptcenter/get-file-meta-data-function-f9e8d804).
2. In a Powershell window with Admin Privileges, I gave my self permission to run unsigned scripts using the command `Set-ExecutionPolicy Unrestricted`.
3. I loaded the script into memory using the command `C:\Users\<username>\Desktop\Get-FileMetaDataReturnObject.ps1`.
4. I created an object that contained all of the metadata properties for every folder and file in the screenshots folder with the command `$fileMeta = Get-FileMetaData -folder (gci "C:\Program Files (x86)\Steam\userdata\<user_id>\760\remote" -Recurse -Directory).FullName`. **This took three hours to complete on my machine.**
5. I then exported the specific properties I needed using the command `$fileMeta | select Path, Kind, "Date taken" | Export-Csv -Path "C:\Users\<username>\Desktop\screenshots.csv" -Encoding ASCII -NoTypeInformation`.
6. In Notepad++, I marked all lines that contained the word `thumbnails` (to ignore the auto-generated thumbnails subfolder Steam created), `Folder` (to ignore folders in general) and `,"?` (for some reason, it appears Powershell couldn't properly parse out the dates and appended a question mark to the beginning of each one, but this helped me easily filter out null values) and deleted them.
7. I was then left with a list of files that needed to be backed up to Google Photos.

It would probably be easier to just retain the last upload date and use the Windows search command `datecreated: d/m/yyyy .. d/m/yyyy` (range between the last upload date and now, using Australian format), but either method requires a bit of jigging about to filter out stuff you don't need, like thumbnails, while retaining the organisation (i.e. what game each screenshot is from).